# Как плавно проскролить страницу вниз до опреденного элемента?

Tags: jquery

Есть у меня следующий код, который должен плавно скролить страницу вниз до опреденного элемента. Но не могу понять, почему он не работает, где ошибка?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a[href^="#"], a[href^="."]').click(function(e) {
    var scrоll_el = $(this).attr('href');
    if ($(scroll_el).length != 0) {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(scroll_el).offset().top
      }, 500);
    }
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
.one,
.two {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.one {
  background-color: chocolate;
}

.two {
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one"><a href="#gold">Ссылка</a></div>
<div id="gold" class="two">Элемент</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш код рабочий, ошибка в опечатке в названии переменной **scrоll_el** (вероятно русские символы)

Примеры плавного скролла с использование jquery оставлю:

Пример:

```js
$('.flowing-scroll').on('click', function() {
  var el = $(this);
  var dest = el.attr('href'); // получаем направление
  if (dest !== undefined && dest !== '') { // проверяем существование
    $('html').animate({
        scrollTop: $(dest).offset().top // прокручиваем страницу к требуемому элементу
      }, 500 // скорость прокрутки
    );
  }
  return false;
});
```

```css
.one,
.two {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.one {
  background-color: chocolate;
}

.two {
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="one"><a href="#goToMe" class="flowing-scroll other-class">Ссылка</a></div>
<div id="goToMe" class="two">Элемент</div>
```

Ваш код в рабочем виде:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a[href^="#"], a[href^="."]').click(function(e) {
    var scrоll_el = $(this).attr('href');
    if ($(scrоll_el).length != 0) {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(scrоll_el).offset().top
      }, 500);
    }
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
.one,
.two {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.one {
  background-color: chocolate;
}

.two {
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one"><a href="#gold">Ссылка</a></div>
<div id="gold" class="two">Элемент</div>
```